An Ampleness Criterion
Let $X/k$ be a scheme over base field $k$ and $L$ an ample bundle. There are several equivalent characterizations for beeing ample (see eg. AG by Goertz & Wedhorn, Prop. 13.47.
One of those is that open subsets $X_f,$ where $ f \in \Gamma(X, L^n), n \ge 1$ (...openness easy to check affine locally) form basis of topology of $X$.
Question: Is it possible to show that one can find a $n_0$ such that already $X_f$ for $f \in \Gamma(X,  L^n)  $ with $n \le n_0$ form a basis for topology of $X_K$ under ampleness assumption for $L$?
Maybe, if we add to $X$ some additional finiteness assumption, eg Noetherian?
Motivation: The remarked gap in this answer.
#EDIT/UPDATE: Think the claim is wrong: passing to very ample $L^n$ (...so embedding $X$ in projective space $\Bbb P^m$) the question disguises as the geometric problem if there exist a $n_0$ such that for any $x_1,..., x_d \in \Bbb P^m$ point there exist a homogeneous polynomial $f$ of degree $n \le n_0$ with $x_1,..., x_d \in V_+(f)$ (...pay attention to order of quantors). That's not possible for fixed bound $n_0$; as $d$ can be arbitrary.
